# How to remove the border line in picker (iOS - react-native)

Tags: react-native, picker

I need to remove the border which shown default from the picker. I have designed the border grey color with 1.5 borderWidth. But it shows a border in a thin line.

```
import { Picker } from 'react-native';

<View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row',borderColor:"transparent",alignItems:'center',marginBottom:13,}}>
  <Picker
    style={{paddingHorizontal: 1,  borderWidth:1.5, borderRadius:4,borderRightWidth:1, borderColor: isValidNumber ? 'grey': 'red', color: 'red', flex:0.5}}
    itemStyle={{height: 47,backgroundColor: "white",borderColor:"transparent",fontSize: 15, fontWeight:'400'}}>
    <Picker.Item style={{borderColor:"transparent"}} key={dialCode} value={dialCode} label={dialCode} />
  </Picker>
<View>
```

[image]

Comment: add ```borderWidth: 0``` to picker style.

Comment: borderWidth: 0 in the picker style needed for e. I have added border width:0 for itemStyle. it not worked. Note: The above screenshot has two borderline. One is grey color with bored 1.5. It needed for me. Another one border is there need to remove that

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set { borderWidth: 1; borderColor: 'white'; } to itemStyle and it helped me to hide those lines.